# How to export data from firestore using vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I want to export data from firestore.

I tried running the following code.

```
firebase firestore:export data.json
```

Tried multiple things and still can get an output file with the data in my database.

> Error: firestore:export is not a Firebase command

To fix the error I uninstall the :

```
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools

npm cache clean --force
```

Then I run
`firebase --version`, which is really up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing two separate command line tools:

- `gcloud` from the Google Cloud Platform
- `firebase` from Firebase

The `firestore export` command is only present in the `gcloud` CLI, and documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/export) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import#gcloud). There is no equivalent command in the Firebase CLI, for which the options are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli).